# How are companies using Google's OAuth for RBAC?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I'm working on an application which uses role-based access control to limit what users can do. I would like to support authentication using OpenID Connect with the major identity providers such as Google. I'm having a hard time figuring out how companies usually use Google as the IdP for their organization.

I was able to make the regular login flow work, but I have no idea how to get any kind of role or group membership information in the JSON Web Key I receive from Google's OAuth server. I'm quite confused by the whole landscape of Google's authentication since there is IAM and Identity Platform which seem to be doing the same things.

**How do large companies use Google's authentication if they rely on groups or roles for access control?**